# PHPExcel - Preserve rich text format on import

Tags: php, html, sql, phpexcel

A component of a project I am working on is to import text in cells from Excel using PHPExcel as a quicker way to populate the MySQL database.
How can I achieve preserving the Rich Text formatting of the Cell Contents e.g. "The **Quick** Brown *Fox*".

I am guessing it would require parsing the content-format somehow into matching HTML tags? Is there a way to achieve this in PHPExcel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mentioned in the documentation.

```
    $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
    $objRichText->createText('This invoice is ');

    $objPayable = $objRichText->createTextRun('payable within thirty days after the end of the month');
    $objPayable->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setItalic(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );

    $objRichText->createText(', unless specified otherwise on the invoice.');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($objRichText);
```